# Mobile device detection on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to make a Tumblr theme that will show one div if the user is on iOS (with an app store link) and one if they are on anything else (with another link). However, because of the way Tumblr works, I can't figure out why it won't work. I tried to use https://www.mattcromwell.com/detecting-mobile-devices-javascript/, which was written with Wordpress in mind, and I don't quite understand what I'm missing from tumblr.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = { 
    iOS: function() { return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i); }, 
    any: function() { return (isMobile.iOS();} };
</script>
```

is what I have in the head tag. Then, I need the actual detection to happen in the footer, where I have

```
<p id="is-mobile" class="hide">This is a Mobile Device</p>
<p id="is-desktop" class="hide">This is NOT a Mobile Device</p>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(function($) {
         if (!isMobile.iOS())
             $('#is-mobile').addClass('show');
         if (isMobile.iOS())
             $('#is-desktop').addClass('show');
    });
</script>
```

Maybe I have the other jQuery in the wrong place? I have also imported the jQuery library too. Hopefully someone can help me! When I do this, it never shows any div regardless of device (obviously since I have them hidden - and I do have a thing in css that does not show .hide classes).

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the first parenthesis here is a stray one : `return (isMobile.iOS();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shikkediel pointed out, there seems to be an issue with the iOS function.

I've made this fiddle. I also think maybe the condition needed to be inverted (at least now in the fiddle the div for desktop is showing on desktop, and the one for mobile only on mobile).

https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/fvau9vnz/

This is the code:

```
var isMobile = { 
    iOS: function() { 
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)
    }, 
    any: function() { 
        return (isMobile.iOS())
    } 
};

jQuery(function($) {
    if (isMobile.iOS()){ // we should only need an if/else here now. Changed from !isMobile.iOS(); 
        $('#is-mobile').addClass('show');
    }else{
        $('#is-desktop').addClass('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it finally. I appreciate it SO much!

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr allows custom CSS, no?

You can go by device screen size, so you won't have to rely on user agent (which can be [spoofed](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/) and/or not work at times).

Something like this (CSS):

```
#is-mobile{ /* Hide it by default */
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    #is-mobile{ /* If the screen is <= 500px, display it */
        display:block;
    }
}
```

I'm not that familiar with how Tumblr works, but this is how I'd detect mobile devices in normal web design.

For media queries based on each device, [check this out](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

[More info on the css @media rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: this is a much better method of course. Initially I read the question as the OP wanted to specifically target iOS users for some reason. In tumblr you have to override the default mobile layout, but it's just a switch.